# OpenGL rotating textured planes in 3D space

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm wondering if anyone could point me to any resources that would deal in rotating one or several 2D textured planes in 3D space. Something like this but with openGL (preferably C++):

[image: 2D Planes in 3D space]

I'm attempting to do pretty much the exact same thing but no matter how I order my operations I'm getting right-screwy results. So I figure asking for some resources on the subject is better than posting tons of code and asking for people to fix my problems for me. :)

Comment: Thanks for the drive-by downvote. If you want to downvote questions can you explain why? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Maybe it's because your question lacks some screenshot of what your messed up result looks like, some code would be great, too. Without that kind of information, we have to gaze crystal balls, and at least mine is broken right now.

Comment: Actually if you read the question, I said I was looking for resources/tutorials on how to accomplish the effect in question, which I also supplied a screenshot of. And, from the information I provided, celem was able to accurately point me directly to a resource which solved my problem. Nobody was asking anyone to look into crystal balls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you havent already, do a search for 'NeHe tutorials'.  An excellent set of OpenGL tutorials.

Here is a link to the rotation tutorial, includes all the source code in downloadable format and the tutorial walks you through each relevant line.

http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/rotation/14001/

I believe this is working in a 2D space, the step up to 3D probably involves a bit more matrix math but...doable

Comment: Thanks, looking over the source code here I found that the origin of my issue was in screwing up my perspective setup. Thanks again. :)

Comment: welcome, bear in mind as Stefan answered that these tutorials are a little dated, so watch out for obsolete calls:)

Comment: Yeah I realize that. I've decided though not to worry a ton about tracking what has been deprecated in GL because it seems every time they turn around they add stuff, then deprecate it, then the only solution left is to do what they used to provide for you already but manually. (Example, gluLookAt).

Answer (score 1):

The NeHe tutorials are a very popular place to learn the basics of OpenGL. In particular, the tutorial about texture mapping should help you:
http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/texture_mapping/12038/

Mind you though that these tutorials are written for older OpenGL versions which are more beginner friendly IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into scene graphs. Basically it is a way to define a bunch of objects (2D textured planes) and their transforms in 3D space. This allows you to define transforms that work on multiple nodes (objects) as well as single nodes. You can make a pretty simple one in C++ with little effort, or use one such as OpenSG or OSG (slight learning curve needed).

Wikipedia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph